# ZedGraph decrease dist between label and axis labels?

Tags: c#, customization, zedgraph

How to decrease distance between chart label and axis labels?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `TitleGap` property of the `GraphPane` and the `Scale.LabelGap` property of the axis of interest.

For example:

```
zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.TitleGap = 0f;
zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale.LabelGap = 0f;
zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.YAxisList[0].Scale.LabelGap = 0f;
```

will produce the following graph, where the gaps to the title and scale labels are reduced to zero:

[image: Zero gap]

The gaps are given in fractions of the graph pane (I think). You may want to experiment with this...

Furthermore, you can change the `Margin` property of the `GraphPane` to control the margin of the pane to the parent control, for example:

```
zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.Margin.Top = 0f;
```